# Correction of the Interpretation of the SAS code

Tags: xcode, sas, coding-style

I am pretty new to sas. Can you please help me to interpret the following lines of code:

```
proc means data=crsp1 noprint;
var ret;
by gvkey datadate year;
output out=exec_roll_vol_fyear n=nrollingstd std=rollingstd;
run;

data volatility;
set exec_roll_vol_fyear;
where &start_year <= year <= &end_year;
* we have volatility of monthly returns,
converting to annual volatility;
estimated_volatility=rollingstd*(12**0.5);
proc sort nodupkey;
by gvkey year;
run;
```

Does it mean the following: take data "crsp1" and create a dataset "exec_roll_vol_fyear" that will contain rolling standard deviation of "ret"? (I dont quite see what "proc means" stands for here)

Second part: use data "exec_roll_vol_fyear" to create a data set "volatility", where estimated_volatility=rollingstd*(12**0.5) and drop duplicates of gvkey year. Am I  right?

Comment: No, PROC MEANS does not calculate moving statistics, it calculates summary statistics, in this case N and STD for the variable RET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PROC MEANS` is a summarization procedure that summarizes data.  In this case, it will calculate the n and standard deviation for each unique combination of `gvkey datadate year`, and output to a dataset `exec_roll_vol_fyear`.  This might be a "rolling" standard deviation if the incoming data is structured appropriately to do that (basically, if `datadate` defines the rolling windows and if any given record is duplicated once for each window it falls in); impossible to tell. There are better tools for time series analysis in SAS, though.

Then, the data step applies a formula to create a new variable from the standard deviation, and then it sorts the resulting dataset removing duplicates by gvkey and year.